# Java Array Index Out of Bounds Exception

Tags: java, arrays

I run through the entire code. I am able to enter a simple .txt file to search for a word. After it asks for a word, it returns

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -48
    at SearchEngine.main(SearchEngine.java:150)

Line 150 is for (int j = 0; j

Any help debugging?

This is basic search engine program that should be able to search a .txt file for any word.

Assignment link: http://cis-linux1.temple.edu/~yates/cis1068/sp12/homeworks/concordance/concordance.html

---

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class SearchEngine {


    public static int getNumberOfWords (File f) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int numWords = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
        numWords++;
        scan.next();
        }
        scan.close();

        return numWords;
    }

    public static void readInWords (File input, String [] x) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(input);
        int i = 0;
        while (scan.hasNext() && i<x.length) {
            x[i] = scan.next();
            i++;
            }
        scan.close();
    }

    public static int getNumOfDistinctWords (File input, String [] x) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(input);
        int count = 0;
        int i = 1;
        while (scan.hasNext() && i<x.length) {
        if (!x[i].equals(x[i-1])) {
        count++;
        }
        i++;
        }
        scan.close();
        return count;
    }

    public static void readInDistinctWords (String [] x, String [] y) {
        int i = 1;
        int k = 0;
        while (i<x.length) {
            if (!x[i].equals(x[i-1])) {
            y[k] = x[i];
            k++;
            }
        i++;
        }
    }

    public static int getNumberOfLines (File input) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int numLines = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(input);
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            numLines++;
            scan.nextLine();
            }
        scan.close();
        return numLines;
    }

    public static void readInLines (File input, String [] x) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(input);
        int i = 0;
        while (scan.hasNextLine() && i<x.length) {
            x[i] = scan.nextLine();
            i++;
            }
        scan.close();
    }



public static void main(String [] args) {

     try {

        //gets file name
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the text file you wish to search");
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileName = kb.nextLine();
        String TXT = ".txt";
        if (!fileName.endsWith(TXT)) {
            fileName = fileName.concat(TXT);
        }

        File input = new File(fileName);

    //First part of creating index
    System.out.println("Creating vocabArray");
    int NUM_WORDS = getNumberOfWords(input);
    //System.out.println(NUM_WORDS);
    String [] wordArray = new String[NUM_WORDS];
    readInWords(input, wordArray);
    Arrays.sort(wordArray);
    int NUM_DISTINCT_WORDS = getNumOfDistinctWords(input, wordArray);
    String [] vocabArray = new String[NUM_DISTINCT_WORDS];
    readInDistinctWords(wordArray, vocabArray);
    System.out.println("Finished creating vocabArray");



    System.out.println("Creating concordanceArray");
    int NUM_LINES = getNumberOfLines(input);
    String [] concordanceArray = new String[NUM_LINES];
    readInLines(input, concordanceArray);
    System.out.println("Finished creating concordanceArray");



    System.out.println("Creating invertedIndex");
    int [][] invertedIndex = new int[NUM_DISTINCT_WORDS][10];
    int [] wordCountArray = new int[NUM_DISTINCT_WORDS];
    int lineNum = 0;
        while (lineNum<concordanceArray.length) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(concordanceArray[lineNum]);
            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                int wordPos = Arrays.binarySearch(vocabArray, scan.next());
                wordCountArray[wordPos]+=1;
                for(int i = 0; i < invertedIndex.length; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < invertedIndex[i].length; j++) {
                if (invertedIndex[i][j] == 0) {
                invertedIndex[i][j] = lineNum;
                break;
                } } }
                }
            lineNum++;
            }
    System.out.println("Finished creating invertedIndex");

    }
System.out.println("Enter a word to be searched (type quit to exit program)");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String searchWord = keyboard.next();
    while (!searchWord.equals("quit")) {
        int counter = 0;

                    int wordPos = Arrays.binarySearch(allWordsArray, searchWord);
            for (int j = 0; j<invertedIndex[wordPos].length; j++) {
                if(invertedIndex[wordPos][j] != 0) {
                       int number = invertedIndex[wordPos][j];
                       String printOut = concordanceArray[number];
                                               System.out.print(number);
                                               System.out.print(" :");
                                               System.out.println(printOut);
                                    }
            }

            }        



        catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
        System.out.println("File Not Found");
    }




    } //main
} //class
```

Comment: In general, just update your existing question, don't post a new one...

Comment: I know tofu suggested that you should start a new question, and that's usually good advice, but there is some onus on you to indicate that your last question is _solved_ and this is a _new_ question that is logically distinct.

Comment: user1302023, we need to know where line 126 is for us to help you. Your error means that you've asked for a value from your array that doesn't exist. This is an example:   int[] x= new int array[1]  int y= x[10]    because there is no 10 in the array, it give you your error. find where you've done that and you can fix it, or tell us which line is 126.

Comment: I think the line 126 is:              y[k] = x[i]; Though I used my hands to mesure it.

Comment: Line 126 is wordCountArray[wordPos]+=1;

That was for the instruction: Add 1 to the element of wordCountArray at position wordPos.

Comment: your error is on the line above.  Arrays.binarySearch() it returns a -1 if it can't find whatever it is searching for.  So when you call [wordPos] you are likely saying [-1] and of course that's going to blow up!  :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see your `getNumOfDistinctWords(String[] x)` is wrong. This is returning a value of one less than it should be. Here is a modified version of the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class SearchEngine {


    //Counts the number of words in the file
    public static int getNumberOfWords (File f) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int numWords = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            numWords++;
            scan.next();
        }
        scan.close();

        return numWords;
    }


    public static void readInWords (File input, String[] x) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(input);
        int i = 0;
        while (scan.hasNext() && i < x.length) {
            x[i] = scan.next();
            i++;
        }
        scan.close();
    }

    public static String[] getNumOfDistinctWords (String[] x) throws FileNotFoundException {

        HashSet<String> distinctWords = new HashSet<String>();
        for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++){
            distinctWords.add(x[i]);
        }

        String[] distinctWordsArray = new String[distinctWords.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for(String word : distinctWords){
            distinctWordsArray[i] = word;
            i++;
        }


        return distinctWordsArray;
    }

    public static int getNumberOfLines (File input) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int numLines = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(input);
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            numLines++;
            scan.nextLine();
        }
        scan.close();
        return numLines;
    }

    public static void readInLines (File input, String [] x) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(input);
        int i = 0;
        while (scan.hasNextLine() && i<x.length) {
            x[i] = scan.nextLine();
            i++;
        }
        scan.close();
    }



    public static void main(String [] args) {

        try {

            //gets file name
            System.out.println("Enter the name of the text file you wish to search");
            Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
            String fileName = kb.nextLine();
            String TXT = ".txt";
            if (!fileName.endsWith(TXT)) {
                fileName = fileName.concat(TXT);
            }

            File input = new File(fileName);

            //First part of creating index

            System.out.println("Creating vocabArray");
            int NUM_WORDS = getNumberOfWords(input);

            //Output the number of words in the file
            System.out.println("Number of words is: " + NUM_WORDS);


            String[] allWordsArray = new String[NUM_WORDS];
            readInWords(input, allWordsArray);
            Arrays.sort(allWordsArray);
            String[] distinctWordsArray = getNumOfDistinctWords(allWordsArray);

            //Output the number of distinct words
            System.out.println("Number of distinct words is: " + distinctWordsArray.length);
            System.out.println("Finished creating distinctWordsArray");

            System.out.println("Creating concordanceArray");
            int NUM_LINES = getNumberOfLines(input);
            String[] concordanceArray = new String[NUM_LINES];
            readInLines(input, concordanceArray);
            System.out.println("Finished creating concordanceArray");

            System.out.println("Creating invertedIndex");
            int [][] invertedIndex = new int[distinctWordsArray.length][10];
            int [] wordCountArray = new int[distinctWordsArray.length];


            int lineNum = 0;
            while (lineNum < concordanceArray.length) {
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(concordanceArray[lineNum]);

                while (scan.hasNext()) {
                    //Find the position the word appears on the line, if word not found returns a number less than 0
                    int wordPos = Arrays.binarySearch(distinctWordsArray, scan.next());

                    if(wordPos > -1){
                        wordCountArray[wordPos] += 1;
                    }


                    for(int i = 0; i < invertedIndex.length; i++) {
                        for(int j = 0; j < invertedIndex[i].length; j++) {
                            if (invertedIndex[i][j] == 0) {
                                invertedIndex[i][j] = lineNum;
                                break;
                            } } }
                }
                lineNum++;
            }
            System.out.println("Finished creating invertedIndex");

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found");
        }

    } //main
} //class
```

I should also point out the fact that `Arrays.binarySearch(distinctWordsArray, scan.next());` will return a number less than 0 if the word is not found on that line. This is why you are getting the `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1` as `wordCountArray` is being referenced at index -1 which of course doesn't exist!

The code after this also looks buggy but I'll let you fix that!!

Comment: Ok, I edited the post to contain my last problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly where line 126 is, finding this specific bug is just too much hassle. But I've got some advice for the rest of the code:

```
int NUM_DISTINCT_WORDS = getNumOfDistinctWords(input, wordArray);
```

Normally, variables in all-caps are *constants* that are assigned at compile time. It's a tradition that comes from C days, when it was wonderful to know which "variables" were actually replaced by the preprocessor. But the convention has proven to be useful in other languages, and most programmers would expect `NUM_DISTINCT_WORDS` to be assigned a specific value at compile time.

This code is simply unreadable:

```
            for(int i = 0; i < invertedIndex.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < invertedIndex[i].length; j++) {
            if (invertedIndex[i][j] == 0) {
            invertedIndex[i][j] = lineNum;
            break;
            } } }
```

A more idiomatic way to show these nested loops is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < invertedIndex.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < invertedIndex[i].length; j++) {
        if (invertedIndex[i][j] == 0) {
            invertedIndex[i][j] = lineNum;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Because I use the standard `Lindent` script to do re-indenting, I get tabs. You don't *have* to use tabs, but they are convenient to add and delete with a single keystroke, and they are deep enough to be obviously visible even with smallish type faces. You'll find your code far easier to work with if you follow the standard indenting idioms.

The following piece of code is extremely unfortunate:

```
catch(FileNotFoundException exception) {
    System.out.println("File Not Found");
}
```

It would be better to catch a higher-level exception *and include the exception message*. You can more easily handle dozens of errors if you catch an exception higher in the hierarchy, and the error messages will be far more informative.

Your `main()` method performs a *lot* of detailed work. I think your code would be easier to test, easier to debug, and easier to read, if you break it apart into more methods. Try to get the `main()` to read practically like a high-level description of your code.

---

With the line with the bug on it now easily visible, I can spot the problem:

```
            int wordPos = Arrays.binarySearch(vocabArray, scan.next());
            wordCountArray[wordPos]+=1;
```

You've looked up the `wordPos` in the `vocabArray`, but modified content in the `wordCountArray`. Are you *sure* they are [the same size and have the same meanings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array)?

Comment: http://cis-linux1.temple.edu/~yates/cis1068/sp12/homeworks/concordance/concordance.html

This is the link to the instructions that I'm following. When I initialize both vocabArray and wordCountArray, both are created using  the same variable and should be the same size.

Comment: Ah, and that explains the variable names, too. :) Fair enough. I'd do a giant pile of tests on the `binarySearch()` method; make sure that it is always returning results you expect. Perhaps your array isn't sorted correctly?

Comment: And as far as the methods go, I like to write out each section in the main, then decomp it into methods. I just haven't gotten to that step yet. 

The answer below seems to have taken care of the issue thus far.